# How to retrieve data from mysql database joining 5 different tables

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I am trying to retrieve data from mysql database from 5 different table but it did not work as it should and it did not display anything.

tables are :

- site_info
- site_coordinates
- owner_info
- subcontractor_info
- company_info

site_info:

- siteID
- companyID
  -siteNAME
- ownerID
- subcontractorID
- equipmentTYPE

site coordinates:

- siteID
- latitude
- longitude
- height

owner_info:

- ownerID
- ownerNAME
- ownerCONTACT

subcontractor_info:

- subcontractorID
- subcontractorCOMPANY
- subcontractorNAME
- subcontractorCONTACT

company_info:

- companyID
- companyNAME

## mysql query:

```
select 
     site_info.siteID,site_info.siteNAME ,site_info.equipmentTYPE,site_coordinates.latitude,site_coordinates.longitude,site_coordinates.height ,owner_info.ownerNAME,owner_info.ownerCONTACT,company_info.companyNAME,subcontractor_info.subcontractorCOMPANY,subcontractor_info.subcontractorNAME,subcontractor_info.subcontractorCONTACT   
from `site_info`
INNER JOIN `owner_info`
  on site_info.ownerID = owner_info.ownerID
INNER JOIN `company_info`
  on site_info.companyID = company_info.companyID
INNER JOIN `subcontractor_info`
  on site_info.subcontractorID = subcontractor_info.subcontractorID
INNER JOIN `site_coordinates`
  on site_info.siteID=site_coordinates.site_id
where owner_info.ownerID = 159
```

Where is my error, and is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Try to make every INNER JOIN a LEFT JOIN and let us know if you get records back.

Comment: That's what the error functions are for.

Comment: are you getting any errors, or just no data being returned?

Comment: there is no error  phpmyadmin display this message **MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0005 seconds.)**

Comment: OK, so there is not issue with your query other than it returns no data. We cannot tell you why, we do not know the content of your database...

Comment: Is there an actual error, or did you just get no results? Since you're doing an inner join, there needs to be a match as specified by the joins in each of the five tables; if any are missing, you'll get no rows returned. If you want to return results from one table whether or not there are matching rows in the others, use a LEFT JOIN instead.

Comment: Here's a great [visual explanation of joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: i will update my question  by adding the fields for each table

Comment: Try without `where` and with a `limit 1`

Answer (score 1):

I solve it  just needed to change to the LEFT JOIN .

so the  updated query looks:

```
select 
site_info.siteID,site_info.siteNAME ,site_info.equipmentTYPE,site_coordinates.latitude,site_coordinates.longitude,site_coordinates.height ,owner_info.ownerNAME,owner_info.ownerCONTACT,company_info.companyNAME,subcontractor_info.subcontractorCOMPANY,subcontractor_info.subcontractorNAME,subcontractor_info.subcontractorCONTACT from `site_info`
LEFT JOIN `owner_info`
on site_info.ownerID = owner_info.ownerID 
LEFT JOIN `company_info` 
on site_info.companyID = company_info.companyID
LEFT JOIN `subcontractor_info` 
on site_info.subcontractorID = subcontractor_info.subcontractorID
LEFT JOIN `site_coordinates` 
on site_info.siteID=site_coordinates.siteID 
where owner_info.ownerID = 159
```

thank you for your comments and answers

Comment: With regard to owner_info, `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x...` is identical to `INNER JOIN x...`

Answer (score 0):

The Query is syntactically correct. Since you are facing output problems check your Relation Algebra. Are you using the right JOIN conditions between them? If each of the two tables has a common attribute you can perform Natural Join ie without giving conditions, the common attribute will be sorted out and I would write such complex queries using ALIAS 'AS' keyword.

```
SELECT
     site_info.siteID,
     site_info.siteNAME,
     site_info.equipmentTYPE,
     site_coordinates.latitude,
     site_coordinates.longitude,
     site_coordinates.height,
     owner_info.ownerNAME,
     owner_info.ownerCONTACT,
     company_info.companyNAME,
     subcontractor_info.subcontractorCOMPANY,
     subcontractor_info.subcontractorNAME,
     subcontractor_info.subcontractorCONTACT        
FROM `site_info` AS SI JOIN `owner_info` AS OI
  ON SI.ownerID = OI.ownerID 
  JOIN `company_info` AS CI
  ON SI.companyID = CI.companyID 
  JOIN `subcontractor_info` AS SUBI
  ON SI.subcontractorID = SUBI.subcontractorID 
  JOIN `site_coordinates` AS SC
  ON SI.siteID=SC.site_id
WHERE owner_info.ownerID = 159;
```